# Build a Custom Tokenizer for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch2

I'm building a custom tokenizer in response to this: [Performance of doc_values field vs analysed field](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/performance-of-doc-values-field-vs-analysed-field/99445/2)

None of this API appears to be documented (?), so I'm going off of code samples from other plugins/tokenizers, but when I restart elastic having deployed my tokenizer I get this error constantly in the logs:

```
[2017-09-20 08:45:37,412][WARN ][indices.cluster          ] [Samuel Silke] [[storm-crawler-2017-09-11][3]] marking and sending shard failed due to [failed to create index]
[storm-crawler-2017-09-11] IndexCreationException[failed to create index]; nested: CreationException[Guice creation errors:

1) Could not find a suitable constructor in com.cameraforensics.elasticsearch.plugins.UrlTokenizerFactory. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
  at com.cameraforensics.elasticsearch.plugins.UrlTokenizerFactory.class(Unknown Source)
  at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.TokenizerFactoryFactory.create(Unknown Source)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider2.initialize(Unknown Source)
  at _unknown_

1 error];
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.createIndex(IndicesService.java:360)
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.cluster.IndicesClusterStateService.applyNewIndices(IndicesClusterStateService.java:294)
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.cluster.IndicesClusterStateService.clusterChanged(IndicesClusterStateService.java:163)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService.runTasksForExecutor(InternalClusterService.java:610)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:772)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:231)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) Could not find a suitable constructor in com.cameraforensics.elasticsearch.plugins.UrlTokenizerFactory. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
  at com.cameraforensics.elasticsearch.plugins.UrlTokenizerFactory.class(Unknown Source)
  at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.TokenizerFactoryFactory.create(Unknown Source)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider2.initialize(Unknown Source)
  at _unknown_

1 error
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:360)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.injectDynamically(InjectorBuilder.java:172)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:110)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.createChildInjector(InjectorImpl.java:157)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.createChildInjector(ModulesBuilder.java:55)
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.createIndex(IndicesService.java:358)
    ... 9 more
```

My tokenizer is built for v2.3.4, and the TokenizerFactory looks like this:

```
public class UrlTokenizerFactory extends AbstractTokenizerFactory {

    @Inject
    public UrlTokenizerFactory(Index index, IndexSettingsService indexSettings, @Assisted String name, @Assisted Settings settings){
        super(index, indexSettings.getSettings(), name, settings);
    }

    @Override
    public Tokenizer create() {
        return new UrlTokenizer();
    }
}
```

I genuinely don't know what I'm doing wrong. Have I deployed it incorrectly? It appears to be using my classes according to the logs...

I've only deployed it to one of my es nodes (4-node cluster). The `/_cat/plugins?v` endpoint gives this:

```
name         component          version type url 
Samuel Silke urltokenizer       2.3.4.0 j
```

As there's little or no documentation on this process, I've got this far by copying constructs as created in plugins by other people.

The error I'm seeing doesn't make sense. My TokenizerFactory looks just like everyone else's for this version of elastic. What am I doing wrong or, possibly, not doing that I should be to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing an `Environment` variable. It should have been this:

    `public UrlTokenizerFactory(Index index, IndexSettingsService indexSettings, Environment env, @Assisted String name, @Assisted Settings settings){
...`

I found a similar one here in the end: https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-analysis-kuromoji-neologd/blob/2.3.x/src/main/java/org/codelibs/elasticsearch/kuromoji/neologd/index/analysis/KuromojiTokenizerFactory.java